# How long does it take on average to deliver high priority GCM message IRL?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**Intro:**

I have an Android app that is notified by my server when security related event happens. Currently I am using pull, i.e. the app constantly "pings" th server in order to check for new messages. The problem is that (as expected) it drains the battery. For some users timely notification is more important than the battery life but for others it is quite the opposite and I will implement GCM in order to avoid pinging the server.

**My question is:**

Did someone gathered statistics from the real life how long it takes on average to deliver a push notification to the phone  (Android) (in different phone modes as screen on/off/sleep)?

If you don't have statistics what is roughly your experience? Is it 1 minute / 2 minutes / 5 / 10 minutes? Probably a range will be more usable.

P.S. I've read the docs saying "High priority. This is the default priority for notification messages. GCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately". This simply does not provide enough info.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, GCM did delivered notifications Immediately to phones with screen on (never tested with off) but with the old Android where application services was allowed to stay on while the device was on.

Currently, GCM was migrated to FCM (Firebase CM) and I know that FCM keeps a intermitent shared connection to the push server so it can receive immediatly as well.

Comment: The more interesting part is when the device is sleeping. With one of my previous apps I had delays close to 10 minutes and was wondering if this is still possible to happen (10 minutes is way too much).

Comment: Try migrate to FCM, it overcomes the android battery policy